# Is there an API DocuSign Java SDK to download copy of signed envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

After user completes the embedded signing, is there any API in the Java SDK to download the documents in the envelope in PDF format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The relevant API Method is **Envelopes::getDocument**, which is documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/get

In the Java SDK, that method is used like: `byte[] results = envelopesApi.getDocument(accountId, envelopeId, documentId);`

A more detailed example of this is available in part 7 of the Java Code Grant Example project, available on GitHub: https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant